# Why is my variable nil?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode6, didselectrowatindexpath

courseData is an array of struct objects. Each object has 9 string variables (holeNumber, Par, SI etc)  The cells populate fine but when you click on a row I am trying to get a detail view controller to populate an image view with the variable courseImage relating to that row.
Complete code shown.  courseImage variable still shows nil.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return courseData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Hole") as UITableViewCell

    let item = courseData[indexPath.row]

    let holeLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel
    holeLabel.text = item.holeNumber

    let parLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as UILabel
    parLabel.text = item.par

    let siLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as UILabel
    siLabel.text = item.SI

    let wyLabel = cell.viewWithTag(4) as UILabel
    wyLabel.text = item.whiteYards

    let yyLabel = cell.viewWithTag(5) as UILabel
    yyLabel.text = item.yellowYards

    let ryLabel = cell.viewWithTag(6) as UILabel
    ryLabel.text = item.redYards

    let photo = item.image
    let placeholder = cell.viewWithTag(7) as UIImageView
    placeholder.image = UIImage(named: photo)


    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didselectRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let courseSection = courseData[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row]

    var tipPic = courseSection.plan
    var courseImage : UIImage = UIImage(named: tipPic)!

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var destViewController : DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
        if (segue.identifier == "courseTip") {

        destViewController.receivedPic = courseImage
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are adding your code in didDeselect delegate method which means there's currently no selected row.

I believe you meant to do this in your didSelect event.

Comment: Thanks.  Have amended the method but it still shows nil?